# I am building a flutter app. After deleting my database (clear cache from virtual android device) my login function (Firebase) is failing

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

This function was always working before, but i tried to delete my local sfqlite database by clearing the app cache from

My code is based on the 37hours flutter course of vandad (very great) so it has BLOC implementation for login.

I have an authcontroller class, it always returns me a GenericAuthException even when i enter a wrong password or emailadress.

Below is my loginfunction, i am not sure what other info is needed for anyone to help me out

```
@override
Future<AuthUser> logIn({
required String email,
required String password,
}) async {
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email,
    password: password,
  );
  final user = currentUser;
  if (user != null) {
    return user;
  } else {
    throw UserNotFoundAuthException();
  }
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    throw UserNotFoundAuthException();
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    throw WrongPasswordAuthException();
  } else if (e.code == 'invalid-email') {
    throw InvalidEmailAuthException();
  } else {
    throw GenericAuthException();
  }
  } catch (_) {
  throw GenericAuthException();
  }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> logOut() async {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  if (user != null) {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
   } else {
  throw UserNotLoggedInAuthException();
  }
  }
```

Tried adding a different emailadres or password, i still get a generic error.
I have tried removing the app from my virtual device and cold booting it.

My internet connection is also working on the phone.

Does anyone has an idea where i should look?

Comment: If you `print(e)` inside the catch, what does it show?

Comment: if i place the print(e) inside the catch block (like this)
catch (_) {
      print(e);
      throw GenericAuthException();

it shows undefined name 'e'.

Comment: I also have a catch(e) in my Loginbutton, like below.

                onPressed: () async {
                  final email = _email.text;
                  final password = _password.text;
                  try {
                    await AuthController.logIn(email, password);
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                    await showErrorDialog(context, e.toString());
                  }
                },

When i put the print here nothing is printed

Answer (score 0):

I have made a couple of changes in my loginscreen in an earlier build where i have moved some widgets to a separate dart file. This seems to have caused the issue. I have replaced the loginscreen by my old loginscreen and everything seems to work now.